# Javascript isn't setting the Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am not getting any errors. When you look at the `console.log()`'s outputs, the first one gives me the array, and when I open up the 2nd one, it says the array is empty! It's almost as if it was never set. The array I'm checking for is `.axes`.
I can directly access it, but then I can't see it when I expand the object.
This is for the most important thing in my life and the universe is trying to stop me.

```
for(i=0; i<$.count; i+=1){
    h = chain[i];
    h.axes = [ chain[0] ];
    if (i==3){
        console.log('Direct_AXES',h.axes);
        console.log('Direct_H',h);
    }

    chain[0].dna.push(h);

}
```

Comment: Do you have more information about what the content in the array `chain` is?

Comment: please provide details on 'chain' object, h object h.axes, it is not very clear from your code

Comment: that would imply that chain[3] is empty

Comment: You should provide a minimal working example. This may even help you solving your problem. I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at test.html:3" which is quite obvious.

Comment: Ok. well right now I'm turning on and off a "setInterval" that's called after both console.logs. and apparently that's dictating wether or not that array can be shown. so i'm pretty sure there's something astronomically weird going on

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can help you. This works like a charm.

```
var chain = [{},{},{},{},{}];
for(i=0;i<chain.length;i+=1){

    h = chain[i];
    h.axes = [ chain[0] ];

    if (i==3){
        console.log('Direct_AXES',h.axes);
        console.log('Direct_H',h);
    }

   // chain[0].dna.push(h);

}
```

I added an array with four empty objects (so the code would somehow run). And I commented the last line of the loop because obviously I would run into an error. 
Everything is working fine. So the conclusion here is that there is an error in the part you didn't post, because everything is working as expected.
Both logs do print the array and the whole object h containing the axes array.